# my site's radio buttons don't work in IE

Tags: html, css

is there any way to make this work in IE?
I am trying to style a survey and it just will not work in IE6
the hover over is fine but the checked just dosen't work

css:

```
.A label {
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#F36;
    padding:4px 11px;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:16px;
    width:775px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

.A label:hover{
    background-color: #C36;
}

.A input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    background-color: #C36;
}
```

Html:

```
<div class="A">
 <input type="radio" name="price" value="1" id="1PR" checked="checked" /><label for="1PR">£0-2</label><br />
 <input type="radio" name="price" value="2" id="2PR" /><label for="2PR">£3-£5</label><br />
 <input type="radio" name="price" value="3" id="3PR" /><label for="3PR">£6-£8</label><br />
 <input type="radio" name="price" value="4" id="4PR" /><label for="4PR">£9-£11</label><br />
 <input type="radio" name="price" value="5" id="5PR" /><label for="5PR">£12-£14</label>
</div>
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: Aside: the values on all of your radio buttons are the same, which seems like a potential bug.

Comment: i mean that when i select a 'label' it dose not turn pink

Comment: You say you're trying to get it working in IE6? You've got stacks of stuff in your CSS that won't work in IE6. I count five separate CSS features that either aren't supported at all in IE6 or are buggy. The best advice is to drop IE6 support entirely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `:checked` pseudoclass was not supported until IE9.

For earlier versions of IE, there's no way to do it with pure CSS. You need to use Javascript to add a class when the radio button changes. Here is an example using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="radio"]:checked').addClass("checked");
    $('input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $("input.checked").removeClass("checked");
        if ($this.prop("checked")) {
            $this.addClass("checked");
        }
    });
});
```

You can see this code in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/4RnbZ/1/

Comment: that is exactly what I was writing

Comment: ditto that - 2 seconds late to the game :)

Comment: Selectivizr didn't work. it highlighted the radio box when the page loaded but not when i select another one

Comment: In that case you would have to add some custom javascript. Do you have jQuery available?

Comment: Just updated the code so it will add the `checked` class to the default checked item.

Answer (score 0):

:checked css selector is not supported before IE9